# Tracking a cat5 cable

Tags: networking

I am running the stage lights and sound for our Veterans Day assembly and there is a old ip camera cable in the back that has worked before and I'm trying to use a router on it to play a YouTube video. My question is how can I track it to the sever box? I checked the local box that everything on that side of the building is plugged into and there are no unplugged cables but the router does not receive and data from the cable. HELP!!

Answer (score 6):

You need a toner:

[image]

It's a two piece device you can plug on one end of the cable and it then sends a signal back to where it plugs in that you can pick up with a wand that beeps (or makes sounds depending on how you can configure it). Various technology stores have them, but I doubt Best Buy something would. Maybe a hardware store? Home Depot?

Comment: ...and yep, I've seen them at several HD stores.

Comment: (I was getting ready to post an answer w/ the picture when I saw you post your answer, so I just added my picture. Hope that's OK.)

Comment: Is there a way with a laptop?

Comment: No, you need a toner.

Comment: How would I connect it to the wire?

Comment: Toners are made differently. Some have an ethernet port on them you can connect the cable into, some have the red and black cables you can connect onto the cable itself. You then trace the wire from there.